# How to remove "d" wrapper from WCF Data Service using EF4

Tags: .net, json, c#-4.0, wcf-data-services

My question is similar to this one [JsonConvert.DeserializeObject and "d" wrapper in WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1625500/jsonconvert-deserializeobject-and-d-wrapper-in-wcf) but I'm not sure how to implement this for my situation. Here is my complete web.config the WCF Data Service:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>

<location path="MyWcfDataService.svc">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>

    <system.serviceModel>
      <behaviors>
        <endpointBehaviors>
          <behavior name="MyWcfDataServiceBehavior">
            <webHttp defaultOutgoingResponseFormat="Json"/>
          </behavior>
        </endpointBehaviors>
      </behaviors>
    </system.serviceModel>
</location>

</configuration>
```

My Data Service is simple enough:

```
// specifying WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare doesn't seem to have any effect
[WebGet(ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json, 
    BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)] 
public string GetJsonTest(string x)
{

    var json = new
    {
        hello = "world"
    };

    return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(json);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As far as I can tell, it is impossible to remove the 'd'. It is built into Data Services for security reasons.

Answer (score 2):

To expand on Darcy's answer, the d object is necessary to guard against cross site scripting attacks. http://haacked.com/archive/2008/11/20/anatomy-of-a-subtle-json-vulnerability.aspx

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that you are generating the json yourself in the return value, then asking WCF to return your generated json string as json.

You have at least two possible options:

1) Do not specify that WCF formats its response values as JSON and leave your code as is (you assume the responsibility for generating the json in every method).

2) Modify your method to return an instance of the class that you want generated in json (wcf assumes the responsibility for generating the json). To accomplish this, you would need to move the class declaration out of the method.

Comment: 1) returns the exact same thing. `{
"d" : {
"GetJsonTest": "{\"hello\":\"world\"}"
} 
}` 2) I'm using EF so this solution is not trivial nor practical.